# How does the accuser determine which account identified a double baking

Tags: baking

Both the endorser and the baker require you to pass in the account that is baking/endorsing, however the accuser doesn't take any such parameters at startup so I'm wondering how it determines who is responsible for identifying any double baking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to identity who submitted the evidence, because it is the baker who includes the evidence who receives the rewards.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't relevant "who" identified the double baking. Because the Baker, that includes the evidence in (one of the next) Blocks, submits the evidence to the network.

Comment: So how does the baker get the evidence from the endorser?